# How Loop work in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: loops, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation that already generate XML , I need a loop that picks UNIQUE ID from table that will be passed to that transformation using variable and based on unique id multiple XML files will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

use **Job** for that in the first transformation **set variable** or **copy raws to result** and linked to the second transformation in which check  **execution for every raw input** and generate XML files. that's how you can generate a loop in Pentaho.

Comment: Can You please share sample Transformation for the same

Comment: Please see the below link where this guy has explained about loops in Pentaho. apply this concept in your requirements.
https://www.allabouttechnologies.co.in/pentaho/concept-of-loops-in-pentaho/